# CodeIgniter routing when routing url starts with variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, url-routing

I am getting problem on codeigniter routing when routing url starts with variable like following -

```
$route['(:any)/(:any)']  = "home/index/0/N/DealsAmount/ASC/$1/$2";
```

i can to able to configure other routing url when i am passing values through url.
Example: 
Following things work perfectly

```
$route['About-Us/Team'] = "aboutus/team";
$route['About-us/Jobs'] = "aboutus/jobs";
$route['About-Us/FAQ'] = "aboutus/faq";
```

But i use this url using varible like following --

```
$route['About-Us/Team/(:any)'] = "aboutus/team/$1";
$route['About-Us/Team/(:any)/(:any)'] = "aboutus/team/$1/$2";
$route['About-us/Jobs/(:any)'] = "aboutus/jobs/$1";
$route['About-Us/FAQ/(:num)'] = "aboutus/faq/$1";
```

then it redirects to the home page that means this routing is not working here $route['(:any)/(:any)'] is working how can i able to rout these types of url can you please advise me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the routes with `:any` at the bottom. If you put it at the top other routes never get caught. This should be OK:

```
$route['About-Us/Team/(:any)/(:any)'] = "aboutus/team/$1/$2";
$route['About-Us/Team/(:any)'] = "aboutus/team/$1";
$route['About-us/Jobs/(:any)'] = "aboutus/jobs/$1";
$route['About-Us/FAQ/(:num)'] = "aboutus/faq/$1";
$route['(:any)/(:any)']  = "home/index/0/N/DealsAmount/ASC/$1/$2";
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can click the "V" next to my answer to mark your question as solved.